# ORACLE SQL:More than one WHEN MATCHED condition INSIDE MERGE STATEMENT

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I want to use a merge statement in pl/sql and the target table has to be updated on a particular condition. I know we can use multiple when matched condition in sql server with and operator, but i am not sure about Oracle. I am looking for that kind of feature in oracle.

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606)

Comment: you can have only the one  `when matched` part in oracle, but you can define multiple logical conditions within the `ON` part concatenate with `OR` operator

Comment: You can also use where clause in update section to specify condition

Comment: yes i can use a where clause in update section but in-spite of where clause in update section can i have multiple when matched condition inside merge statement where i can update some rows on a particular condition and update some row using another condition and insert when not matched...

Answer (score 0):

```
create table table1 (id number, text varchar2(20));
create table table2 (id number, text varchar2(20), text2 varchar2(20));

insert into table1 values (1,'');
insert into table1 values (2,'');
insert into table1 values (3,'');
insert into table2 values (1,'a','b');
insert into table2 values (2,'a','b');
insert into table2 values (3,'a','b');
insert into table2 values (4,'a','b');
```

I understand you want obtain something like code below with commented line

```
merge into table1 t1
using table2 t2
on (t1.id = t2.id)
when matched then update set
t1.text = t2.text where t1.id = 1
--t1.text = t2.text2 where t1.id = 2
when not matched then insert values (t2.id, t2.text);
```

I would do that like:

```
merge into table1 t1
using (select id, case id when 1 then text when 2 then text2 else null end as tt, text from table2) t2
on (t1.id = t2.id)
when matched then update set
t1.text = t2.tt where t2.tt is not null
--t1.text = t2.text2 where t1.id = 2
when not matched then insert values (t2.id, t2.text);

select * from table1;
```